# How to convert a list of key value pairs to a dynamic object

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic, type-conversion, anonymous-types

Basically I'm trying to convert from:

```
keys[3] = {"id", "name", "comment"}
values[3] = {"1", "Ackerman", "superuser"}
```

to:

```
new { id: "1", name: "Ackerman", comment: "superuser"}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: That is not a "dynamic object"; that is an "anonymous type". Which do you mean?

Comment: @MarcGravell Actually either is fine. I just don't want to and can not explicitly define the class beforehand, as the list is dynamically created.

Comment: k; now - what are `keys` and `values` here? because it isn't obvious. That isn't valid C# syntax... are they arrays? if so, what: `string[][] keys` and `object[][] values`?

Comment: @MarcGravell They are string array.

Comment: have you consider using a dictionary?

Comment: "they are strings" no, they aren't... at least, not in the examples. Please be **very specific** about what `keys` and `values` are. Ideally, with code that compiles so we can be sure about what we are seeing.

Comment: @Selman22 No. They API I'm trying to use asks for something like the anonymous type I describe.

Comment: @hurtchin but: in that case, a "dynamic object" (such as `ExpandoObject`) may not work. You need to be very specific about what the API you are calling expects and supports. Can you be more specific? I don't want to lead you down the wrong path... if you could tell us what API you are trying to use, that might help

Comment: @MarcGravell The API looks for an object that it can loop through the properties. So I need to construct an object. And keys and values are both string array.

Comment: @hurtchin there are at least 3 different ways I could interpret as "loop through the properties" - reflection, type-descriptor, and type-meta-provider; I hate to say it, but once again the **exact** details matter. If it using reflection, you need a `Type` - which means to do what you want would involve a `TypeBuilder`. However, for the other 2: more flexible things are possible. Sorry to be a pain, but the details are **really** important to this question, and drastically affect the usable options.

Comment: and once again: *please* can you be more specific about how `keys` and `values` are defined? this is probably an area that I can give help a lot with (meta-programming is kinda "my thing"), but that requires the question to be well-formed.

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't have the source code, but I tried feed in some anonymous type for testing and it works. And the string lists are in most cased taken from some other source code I better not alter.

Comment: @hurtchin does passing a `Dictionary<string,object>` work? Can you name the API you are using?

Comment: @MarcGravell I think it has some sort of JSON serialization within its internal process, so dictionary seems not work. It's not a public API so I cannot tell the name.

Comment: @hurtchin most json libraries support dictionary

Comment: @MarcGravell I've just tried again and it didn't work. I was just guess it's JSON, because I kind of know that there's some network work on that end.

Comment: @hurtchin allow me to emphasize: translating from key/value pairs to a dynamically generated `Type` is a **lot** of work, and requires knowledge of things like `ILGenerator`, `TypeBuilder`, and other meta-programming concepts. Are you sure there is *no other option*? Because: you wouldn't do this just for fun. I can show you how, but it is **not** trivial

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think wat you want is an Expando object which allows to add dinamically properties:

```
keys[3] = {"id", "name", "comment"}
values[3] = {1, "Ackerman", "superuser"}

dynamic item = new ExpandoObject();
var dItem = item as IDictionary<String, object>;

for(int buc = 0; buc < keys.Length; buc++)
    dItem.Add(keys[buc], values[buc]);
```

After that you can call your object as you will do with any other:

```
var id = item.id;
var comment = item.comment;
item.name = "new name";
```